# Customize localhost domain name for Rails 3 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been searching for like 1 hour now an I can't remember. A few weeks ago I saw an article about a method/gem/server/something to modify the localhost:3000 URL to make it look like myapp.dev, for instance.

Do any of you know that thing I'm looking for?

Sorry if this question is not too detailed and vage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [Pow](http://pow.cx/).

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac you can use [Pow](http://pow.cx/), other systems' solutions aren't quite as neat, as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a dead simple approach to use something other than localhost, and you don't particularly care about still having the port number in your URL, you can just use `lvh.me`, which always just points to 127.0.0.1 (along with any subdomain you throw at it). It's really handy for doing things like subdomain testing without any configuration.